# Return a Count of 0 When No Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

OK, I've looked this up and tried a number of solutions, but can't get it to work. I'm a bit of a novice. Here's my original query -  how can I get it to return 0 for an account when there are no results in the student table?

```
SELECT a.NAME
    ,count(s.student_sid)
FROM account a
JOIN inst i ON a.inst_sid = i.root_inst_sid
JOIN inst_year iy ON i.inst_sid = iy.inst_sid
JOIN student s ON iy.inst_year_sid = s.inst_year_sid
WHERE s.demo = 0
    AND s.STATE = 1
    AND i.STATE = 1
    AND iy.year_sid = 16
    AND a.account_sid IN (
        20187987
        ,20188576
        ,20188755
        ,52317128
        ,20189249
        )
GROUP BY a.NAME;
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

Use an *outer* join, moving the condition on that table into the join:

```
select a.name, count(s.student_sid) 
from account a
join inst i on a.inst_sid = i.root_inst_sid
join inst_year iy on i.inst_sid = iy.inst_sid
left join student s on iy.inst_year_sid = s.inst_year_sid
  and s.demo = 0
  and s.state = 1
where i.state = 1
and iy.year_sid = 16
and a.account_sid in (20187987, 20188576, 20188755, 52317128, 20189249)         
group by a.name;
```

`count()` does not count `null` values, which `s.student_sid` will be if no rows join from `student`.

Comment: @Pரதீப் no - I moved the conditions into the join condition. Have a closer look at the query in my answer.

Comment: My bad.. looked like `where` clause to me :\

Answer (score 1):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` and then `SUM()` over the group where `s.student_sid` is not null:

```
select
    a.name,
    sum(case when s.student_sid is null then 0 else 1 end) as student_count
from account a
join inst i on a.inst_sid = i.root_inst_sid
join inst_year iy on i.inst_sid = iy.inst_sid
left join student s
    on iy.inst_year_sid = s.inst_year_sid
    and s.demo = 0
    and s.state = 1
where i.state = 1
and iy.year_sid = 16
and a.account_sid in (20187987, 20188576, 20188755, 52317128, 20189249)         
group by a.name;
```

This is assuming that all of the fields in the `student` table that you are filtering on are optional. If you don't want to enforce removal of records where, say, `s.state` does not equal 1, then you need to move the `s.state=1` predicate into the `WHERE` clauses.

If, for some reason, you are getting duplicate student IDs and students are being counted twice, then you can change the aggregate function to this:

```
count(distinct s.student_id) as student_count
```

...which is safe to do as `count(distinct ...)` ignores null values.

Comment: Ok thank you, that did the trick. I'm still a little unclear about the left join and the sum() ... but when I have more time I'm going to look into that more. Meanwhile, that helped me, thanks again!

Comment: You can just use `count(s.student_id)` if you prefer. I'm used to using `sum()` for conditional count operations, call it force of habit. The reason for `left join` is that it ensures you don't remove results for `a.name` where there is a zero count of `s.student_id`